# two way communication between class and superclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

[sorry for my weak english]

I have my common superclass `S` for my five specific, but similiar, classes `B1`, 
`B2`, `B3`, `B4` and `B5`.

I want to put 'common' (similiar in each B's) code to S, (and call it by `[super myCommonFunction]`).

It should be ok, but question is that myFunction need to call from inside one 
specific function from `B1`,`B2`,`B3`,`B4`,`B5` (it is the same type function with no arguments, even can have the same name in each),

How to call `self` methods from 'superclass'?

Comment: You want to call from S a method in B1 (or one of the other B's)?

Comment: yes, i want to call from S a method in B1,B2,B3,B4,B5 (depending of which part the S actually is); (I want to call B1->S->B1, B2->S->B2, etc)

Comment: I want to call S method from my B17 or B45 and also make S to execute also B17 or B45 functions (simply i want to reuse some of my functions duplicated in all B's by moving it to S but i need not only to call in S but also make it call back my stuff down here :) If i can call 'empty' function in S and it will 'link' with appriopriate functions in B1-B5 it would be ok, i will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is declare the method you want to call in your superclass, you can leave it's body empty or provide a default implementation if you want.

Then you simply provide further implementations in each subclass, **overriding** the superclass method.

Then when you need to call the method from the superclass you simply use `[self myMethod]` and the correct subclass method will be called instead.

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by @Tom is the one I would use if I'm certain that the methods in the descendant classes always have the same name. If the names can vary based on arbitrary conditions then here is another very flexible approach. You will want to change the method signatures to match your requirements:

```
typedef id (^common_function_callback_t)(void);

@interface S : ...
    - (id) commonFunctionWithCallback:(common_function_callback_t) callback;
@end

@implementation S
- (id) commonFunctionWithCallback:(common_function_callback_t) callback 
{
    // ...
    id someIntermediateResult = callback();
    // ...
    return someFinalResult;
}
@end

@implementation B1 // Similar for all other B's
- (id) myFunction
{
    id someThing = ...;
    id someStuff = [self commonFunctionWithCallback:^() {
             return someThing;
        }];
    // ...
    return someOtherResult;
}
@end
```

Comment: tnx, its a little more complicated and i would like to change my method names in B's (actually they have different names but do the same things arrange sprites on the view's - so i can name them -arrangeSprites) - but tnx for answer it could be usefull later, i shal rethink it L8R

Answer (score -1):

As I understood you want to call different method from `S` class depending on which child class called your `commonFunction`? If so - you can just check what is the instance of `self` and do not call `[super commonFunction]`, but `[self commonFunction]` instead. This will automatically call `[super commonFunction]` because `self` inherits from `super`.

Comment: You can't say that "`self` inherits from `super`" it is a non-sense. self and super both represent the object. Sending message to self or super does note change on which object the message is apply. `super` is just an indication to the compiler to start the method lookup at a specific point in the class hierarchy. More precisely the lookup start at the super class of where super is used. Classes can inherits from each others but instance does not. Anyway self and super are the exact same object (self = super).

Comment: i do not quite understand it - but i think maybe what i want is the opposite; i do not want to call super methods from sub - i want to make may super to call its 'actual' child

Comment: @mathk - my point was since `B` is inherited from `S`, calling `[b1 someMethod]` will call `someMethod` from `S` class if it's not overwritten in `B`.